# Dockerized web app take too long to on http calls

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a dockerized Laravel application and use docker-compose to run the application. When I run the application using docker and make a simple ping API call, it takes less than 200ms to respond. But when I run it using docker-compose, it takes more than 3 seconds to respond.

I used `docker run -it --rm -p 8080:8080 senik_laravel:latest` command to run the container and here is the response time:

```
curl 127.0.0.1:8080/ping -w %{time_total}
```

The response is:

```
PONG
0.180260
```

You see that it takes `0.180260` second to respond.

When I run the application using the `docker-compose` file, it takes more than 3 seconds to respond.

```
curl 127.0.0.1:8080/ping -w %{time_total}
```

The response is:

```
PONG
3.834007
```

You see that it takes `3.834007` seconds to respond.

Here is the full `docker-compose` file:

```
version: '3.7'
networks:
  app_net:
    driver: bridge

services:
  laravel:
    build: 
      context: ./laravel
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: senik_laravel
    volumes:
      - ./laravel:/var/www/html
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    ports:
      - '80:8080'
    networks:
      - app_net
  mysql-master:
    image: 'bitnami/mysql:8.0.19'
    container_name: senik_mysql_master
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'

    volumes:
      - ./mysql_master_data:/bitnami/mysql
      - ./docker-configs/mysql/init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    environment:
    - MYSQL_DATABASE=appdb
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=pass
    - MYSQL_AUTHENTICATION_PLUGIN=mysql_native_password
    networks:
      - app_net

  phpmyadmin:
    image: 'bitnami/phpmyadmin:latest'
    container_name: senik_phpmyadmin
    ports: 
      - '8080:80'
    environment:
      DATABASE_HOST: mysql-master
      PHPMYADMIN_PASSWORD: pass
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - 'phpmyadmin_data:/bitnami'
    depends_on: 
      - mysql-master
    networks: 
      - app_net
volumes:
  phpmyadmin_data:
    driver: local
```

This ping API does not make any database call. It just returns `pong`.

I've tested an API with database call and it takes about 19 seconds to respond.

What's wrong? Is it due to the network configurations?

Comment: Could you add the operating system to the description? When you run it docker-only, that Dockerfile is different? How does that use MySQL?

Comment: I told that it is a simple ping-pong and no database call needed.

Comment: I'm on Mac and the Laravel image build on php:7.3-fpm-alpine

Comment: See this, https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/77

Here are my tips:

- Try not to use shared volume, instead copy the project file inside the dockerfile
- Make  sure your php extension, configuration, and web server (php-fpm or php -s) are the same, php with and without opcache or php-fpm is a different animal

Comment: @ThatBuffDude I think you right and the problem is with the shared volume. I run the docker container with shared volume and the result was as same when I run it with docker-compose. I'm checking docker-sync. Maybe it helps. Thanks

Comment: I used to run several PHP apps in docker in prod, copying all the PHP file into your docker container does make a huge difference, and if I remember correctly even after you copy the file to docker container there will be a very small delayed compared to the one in your host machine. Sorry for not answering your question, I'm too lazy to do a google search go gather the facts to answer this question :P it's just my experience

Comment: Thank you so much. It was so helpful and I got the problem.

Comment: Yeah, contrary to compatible linux distros, on Mac the docker will start a virtual machine. And that virtual machine has no native folder sharing module in the Mac OS, so it's probably using rsync or similar to sync the folders. But the problem is that if you copy the files, as others suggested, then you can't test your changes quickly during development. You always need to copy the files again. If you use VS Code, then a better solution is to use the SSH plugin to develop inside the VM.